# Grep counting with 2 requirements

Tags: regex, bash

Test sample:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello"
exit 1

#exit Lorem Ipsum
#Lorem Ipsum
```

Hello,

so I want to use grep to count the lines which have a '#' in the beginning and have the word 'exit' in it from a .txt file.

I have the code for count all lines with a '#' in the beginning and also the code to count all lines with the word 'exit':

```
AllExitStatements=$(grep -c "exit" $FILE)
Commentlines=$(grep -c "^ *#" $FILE)
```

But I dont know how to combine them to get the lines with a '#' as the first letter in the line and the word 'exit' in the line.
The Output should be 1. `#exit Lorem Ipsum` fullfills both requirements.

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the pipe symbol (`|`) to connect multiple `grep`, indirectly realize the `and` matching of multiple keywords.

```
num_line=$(grep "^ *#" a.txt | grep -cw "exit")
```

Comment: Ah, but I have a question: Why are you using -cw and not only -c ?

Comment: Merry Christmas, too! It exactly matches the word ```exit```, but does not match words such as ```exita```, ```exitbc```, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Count all lines that start with `#` and contain `exit`

```
$ grep -c '^#.*exit' input_file
```

Comment: This works too, thanks :D
And Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 0):

try `grep "^#(.*)?exit(.*)?$" a.txt`?

Comment: Hm, does not work for me... 
But still thx for ur effort and Merry Christmas! :)